# Where is voltage highest in an electric field created by a single positive point charge?

Tags: electrostatics

[image: postive charge in space]

Using this image as a reference, please explain where voltage would be highest. I would have previously learned that charge is greatest where the field lines are most dense but I don't quite understand how the concept behind the relationship between voltage and electric field works.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage due to a point charge is $$V=\frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r}$$ where $Q$ is charge $r$ is the distance from the charge and $\epsilon_0$ is about $8.85 \times 10^{-12}$ , so the voltage is greatest close to the point charge, theoretically infinite at the point charge itself.

One way to visualise (and the definition of) Electric field is that the field lines are showing the force on a unit positive test charge.

$$E=\frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2}$$

For Voltage (potential) imagine if a unit positive charge was placed at a point and released.  It would be repelled away from the (fixed) point charge and gain kinetic energy.  The potential can be imagined as the kinetic energy gained when the unit test charge reaches infinity.

For the attractive case, potential near a negative charge, imagine Voltage being the negative of the work needed to pull the unit positive test charge from the point to infinity.

Comment: Voltage is a technical term which refers to the *difference* in electrical potential between any two points. Your first equation is the electrical potential referenced to zero at infinity.

Comment: @Garvin Douglas,  Thanks Bill